# bash output create file with dd /dev/zero with dialog --gauge

Tags: dd, dialog

I am trying to create a new file (blank file) with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.txt count=10240 bs=10240
```

I also want to use dialog output --gauge, something like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero | pv | dd of=output.dat count=10240 bs=102400 iflag=fullblock | dialog --gauge "testing" 10 70 0
```

I have also tried variations of:

```
(pv -n /dev/zero | dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat  bs=1000M  count=1) | dialog --guage "Creating a file..." 10 70 0
```

However it doesn't work, is just lets me know when the file is completed.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `unbuffer`.

Comment: Never knew about unbuffer, but tried it now same result

Comment: `dialog`is not a UNIX command. Please explain what you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you skip `dialog` and use a 'plain' **`pv`** progress view in the command line like so

```
# dd if=/dev/zero bs=10240 count=102400| bash -c 'pv -s 1g  > /media/sudodus/usbdata/output.dat'
 320MiB 0:00:07 [39,2MiB/s] [=========>                        ] 31% ETA 0:00:15
...
1000MiB 0:00:34 [29,1MiB/s] [===============================>  ] 97%            
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1,0 GB, 1000 MiB) copied, 34,4327 s, 30,5 MB/s
```

I wrote to a USB pendrive to make things slower and easier to 'see'.

Answer (score 1):

Since I've been myself trying to do this, here is a solution.

`pv` writes to stderr, so you need to redirect the output to stdout.

I want to write zeros into a cyphered partition.  So:

```
#dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/swap_crypt bs=1M
    dd: error al escribir en '/dev/mapper/swap_crypt': No queda espacio en el dispositivo
    4269+0 registros leídos
    4268+0 registros escritos
    4475322368 bytes (4,5 GB, 4,2 GiB) copied, 4,1489 s, 1,1 GB/s
```

Since I don't need the output, I tell `dd` not to print anything but errors with `status=none`:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/swap_crypt bs=1M status=none
#
```

Nice, no output! So now I use pv to monitor the progress and since I also know how many bytes were written you can tell to pv to print a percentage base on the bytes transmitted: `-n` writes the percentage and `-s` bytes to transmit:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero | pv -n -s 4475322368 | dd of=/dev/mapper/swap_crypt bs=1M  status=none
16
32
43
52
61
69
77
84
88
dd: error al escribir en '/dev/mapper/swap_crypt': No queda espacio en el dispositivo
100
#
```

Now we redirect the stderr to stdout and pipeline to the `dialog --gauge`:

```
#(dd if=/dev/zero | pv -n -s 4475322368 | dd of=/dev/mapper/swap_crypt bs=1M  status=none) 2>&1 | dialog --title "Status"  --gauge "Writing zeros..." 10 60 0
```

Now you only need to figure out (easy task) before the transfer how many bytes it is going to take and replace the number in the -s parameter of pv.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off-topic, but you can use the `status=progress` operand in `dd` and you'll get something like this:

```
748901888 bytes (749 MB, 714 MiB) copied, 3 s, 250 MB/s
```

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null status=progress count=10240 bs=10240`results in: 
`dd: bad argument: "status=progress"`

Comment: @schily Then your version of `dd` doesn't support it.

Comment: If you mention a feature that is not supported by the standard `dd` then you should name that special `dd` clone.

Comment: @schily It's a standard GNU on Debian 9. But `man dd` on my FreeBSD says `status`  is an extension to POSIX.

Comment: So you are not using a standard UNIX implementation. The FreeBSD implementation does not support it as well and other dd implementations (like e.g. `sdd`) use a different command line argument for that feature since 38 years which is approx., 12 years longer than GNU dd exists.

Comment: @schily 38 is more than I am. But you're saying the other ones do have the status feature?

Comment: None accepts `status=progress` except your special clone.... Check e.g. this: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/sdd.1.html This one e.g. includes support to repair defective disks since a really long time.